# Can I read/watch something that contains superpowers?

Tags: halal-haram

I am very interested in such things and I know that you shouldn't watch what contains magic. But I want to know if superpowers would also be under that category of magic and are also prohibited.
Also, if there is a part of the story that is against Islam (I read a comic that contained prophecy) can I just skip that part and read the rest? The story is a Webtoon and it's called MicroHunter.
Allah knows best and I'm trying to improve. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, kids can read these things to. It just fo entertainment. This isn’t magic because magic is from Jinns. Be careful if a person has weird number codes or someone that ask who is ur mother. Satan does the opposite of Allah.

Comment: Thank you :) , but can I get a source just to be sure.

Answer (score -1):

Salaam,
Of course it is ok. It is for fun and its not like you actually believe in it. Remember, Islam is a simple and beautiful religion. We complicate it ourselves. There is nothing haram about watching these movies. It haram if someone actually practices black magic and/or approached someone to perform it for them. hope this helps. :)
MuslimGap

Comment: I heard that watching magic is haram? Is that true? What would you say to those people? If what you said was true then thank you for relieving me from this stress. May Allah guide us all.

Comment: There are always judgemental and strict people. Personally, I don't think it is haram such as eating Pork. If you are stressed, pray and Allah (swt) will show you the right path and answer. :)

Comment: Oh thank you so much. This is the best way! Barakallahu fiki wa jazaki kulla khair. :)

Comment: of course! Jummah Mubarak and I pray that Allah (swt) guides you and answers your duas:)

Answer (score -5):

Yes you can easily watch this because it is just entertainment  not reality.

Comment: Oh thank you  :)